# How to read this table from Devtool documentation page?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

There is table in [Devtool page](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/). But what do all those single, double, triple pluses and `o`'s and minuses mean? I guess they should say something about speed, but what is considered as *faster*, three pluses or two minuses?

[image]

Comment: The caption immediately above calls it "speed". So what would be better, `---` or `+++`?

Comment: @RadLexus, I really don't know, can you imagine that? Both options can equally reflect *faster*. There should be clear explanation. And what does `o` mean then if minuses and pluses mean speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe we should add a key for this page.

To sum it up. You can think of `o` as representing the baseline, where it will be very comparable to speed of build with out using the `devtool` property.

`+` means that you have a gain
`-` means that you have a loss

The point of the doc is to show case the tradeoffs for using each source map type. 'source-map' is perfectly matched to src but extremely slow. Whereas eval is extremely fast but wraps everything in `eval` inside your bundles.